# Double integral region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have made an [**attempt**](https://www.camscanner.net/share/4qoi4/0/w105s10hzyypy) on a problem from an old exam.

I'm not sure if my method is correct or not, as it differs from the [**teacher's solution**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnmebemxzft05xl/Screenshot%202014-04-16%2015.38.28.png) and I'm unsure of the theory. Does my solution lack any important

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your solution is not correct.

The reason is that you cannot write your double integral as a product of 2 simple integrals as you did, since the integral with respect to $x$ depends on $y$.  When you say "no problem" for this integral (with respect to $x$), you are forgetting that it depends on $x$, so that you cannot simply ignore it when looking at the convergence of your double integral.

What you can do (and I presume what your teacher does), is first compute the integral with respect to $x$ (this will give you something that depends on $y$), and then integrate what you get with respect to $y$.

**Edit.** As suggested by David, you can also integrate first with respect to $y$ and then with respect to $x$.

Comment: Much easier to integrate $x$ first.

Comment: @DavidH If you mean "much easier to integrate first with respect to $x$", I agree; except for the "much".

Comment: but the teacher seems to change the region info $[1,\infty)^2$ which has double the area of the one I drew in my sketch.

Comment: @Etienne oops, you're right, my comment didn't make much sense. I must have been tired. I meant to say it's easier to integrate wrt y first.